# Is it possible to Append in Shotcut without losing focus from the source video's timeline?

Tags: keyboard-shortcut, shotcut

I want to be able to play a video and hit <kbd>I</kbd> to set a trim-in, hit <kbd>O</kbd> to set a trim-out, and hit <kbd>A</kbd> to append that clip to a video track, but let the video continue to play so I can continue selecting clips. (I can use the rewind shortcuts if I miss where I want to trim in or out.)

But when I hit <kbd>A</kbd>, the view changes to that clip, so I have to switch back to the source video through the playlist then continue playing again.

Is there a way to not lose focus on appending?

Comment: Hello. Your question is quite unclear. Which NLE program are you using? By "trim in", do you mean "insert an -in point"? By "append", do you mean "place the clip at the end of a string-out of clips on some other video track"? Where are you playing your source video: in the source monitor or a timeline?

Comment: Is "Shotcut" not... a program? And all the words I'm using are literal functions in Shotcut.

Comment: My bad. I kept reading "shortcut". Carry on!

Comment: Oh, haha. Yea it does look like that.